# LibVLC vlcjni library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I want to make a media player using libVLC on Android. 
When I launch my application, it makes me

```
Can't load vlcjni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedError:Couldn't load vlcjnilibrary... findlibrary returned null
```

I am using eclipse and android ndk path is already set.

I have all the .so files in **jni/libs/armeabi-v7a.**

I still didn't find the solution on the net...
Did I miss something on project configuration ? Help me please ! Thanks !

Comment: have you checked if the .so files are included in the compiled APK file? Just use a (un)zip tool for displaying the file content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I unzip my .apk and yes I see the .so in lib/armeabi-v7a/.

Comment: I just resolved this problem by adding all .so files in lib folder of my project.